# Geometry : $\frac{GA}{GA'}+\frac{GB}{GB'}+\frac{GC}{GC'}=3$

Tags: geometry

Let $G$ be centriod of $\triangle ABC$ and GA, GB, GC cut the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ again at A', B', C' respectively. Prove that $\frac{GA}{GA'}+\frac{GB}{GB'}+\frac{GC}{GC'}=3$.

[image]

My attempt :

Let $D, E, F$ be the midpoints of $BC, CA, AB$ respectively.

$\angle GFE = \angle FCD = \angle C'B'G$ so $C'FEB'$ concyclic.

Similarly, $DEB'A'$ concyclic.

By Power of point, $C'G\cdot FG=GE\cdot GB'=GD\cdot GA'$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $GA*GA'=GB*GB'=GC*GC':=s^2$.

It suffices to prove that $\frac{{GA}^{2}+{GB}^{2}+{GC}^{2}}{s^2}=3$.

Note that $s^2=R^2-OG^2$ and by Leibniz's formula we have ${GA}^{2}+{GB}^{2}+{GC}^{2}+3OG^2=OA^2+OB^2+OC^2=3R^2$.

Substituting the equation in leads to the wanted equation.

(Sorry, my first post, I 'm not good at posting, please forgive.)

Comment: No problem at all, Thank you both.

Comment: Please explain how $GA*GA'=GB*GB'=GC*GC':=s^2$ happens

Comment: @Maverick It's the power of point G to the circle.

Comment: Please, could you put a link to a website that explains Leibniz's formula ?

Comment: Is the Leibniz’s theorem the following one ? Could you give me a proof of it? Let $P$ be an arbitrary point in the plane of the triangle $ABC$ ,
then $AP^2+BP^2+CP^2 =\dfrac13\left(AB^2+BC^2+AC^2\right)+3GP^2$ , where $G$ is the centroid of the triangle.

Comment: @Angelo Sorry I couldn’t find any website, but the proof is pretty straightforward. Just use Cartesian coordinate, and the centroid is the average of three vertices. Then explicitly express the distances as functions of coordinates, and the result follows by simple expansion.

Comment: Is there not a pure Euclidean geometry proof without using Cartesian coordinates? Please, could put in your answer an addendum about an Euclidean geometry proof of Leibniz’s theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

Say $AD =2x$, $BG = 2y$, $CG=2z$ and $A'D = x'$, $B'E=y'$, $C'F=z'$. 
Finally $AB = 2c$, $BC= 2a$ and $AC=2b$.

By the PoP we have: $x'\cdot 3x= a^2$, $y'\cdot 3y=b^2$, $z'\cdot 3z=c^2$ and $$x(x+x') = y(y+y')= z(z+z') =:k$$
Then $$3x^2+a^2 = 3y^2+b^2= 3y^2+c^2=3k$$

So $3(x^2+y^2+z^2)+a^2+b^2+c^2 =9k$

We are interested in $$I= {2x\over x+x'}+ {2y\over y+y'}+ {2z\over z+z'}= {2x^2+2y^2+2z^2\over k}$$

By parallelogram identity we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
  (6x)^2+(2a)^2 &=&  2(2b)^2+2(2c)^2\\
  (6y)^2+(2b)^2 &=&  2(2a)^2+2(2c)^2\\
   (6z)^2+(2c)^2 &=&  2(2b)^2+2(2a)^2\\
\end{eqnarray*}
and so $$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)=a^2+b^2+c^2$$

Thus $2(a^2+b^2+c^2) =9k$ and thus $I= 3$